# Python lxml.html xpath doesn't return any element

Tags: python, xpath, python-requests, lxml

I'm using requests with lxml to grab some content from my website, but sometimes it doesn't return the elements it should. I just tried it on a Wikipedia page and 20% of the time, it doesn't work, here is the code to reproduce the "bug" :

```
import requests
import lxml.html
url= "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Web_crawler&action=edit&section=2"
resp = requests.get(url)
print(resp.text[:500]) #print <title> tag
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(resp.text)
title = tree.xpath('//title') #returns an empty list []
```

as you can see here, when I print the HTML out of requests lib, I see the following :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="client-nojs" lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>Editing Web crawler (section) - Wikipedia</title>
<script>document.documentElement.className="client-js";RLCONF={"wgBreakFrames":!0,"wgSeparatorTransformTable":["",""],"
...
```

You can see the `<title>` tag very clearly, but looks like with the xpath `//title` LXML can't catch it properly. When I print `title` I get a empty list `[]`
This code works just fine for some other URLs like this one `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler`
any thoughts ?

Comment: What do you mean by "LXML can't catch it properly"? What error are you getting?

Comment: I just checked your code. When you `print(title[0])`, it correctly prints out the title.

Comment: @JackFleeting Just updated the question, when I print title, I get an empty list []

Comment: @HarshanaSerasinghe that's weird, it gives me an empty list

Comment: @HarshanaSerasinghe is right; `print(title[0].text)` olutputs `Editing Web crawler (section) - Wikipedia`.

Comment: @JackFleeting so what do you think is the problem on my laptop ? all xpath doesn"t look to work. it all give me empty arrays. thanks

Comment: @DanyM Start by checking if you have the most recent versions of requests and lxml; can't think of anything else at the moment.

Comment: @JackFleeting oh thanks, updating lxml did it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @jackFeeting comment, I updated lxml and my code worked just fine.
`pip3 install --upgrade lxml` updated from version `4.4.1` to `4.6.2`